# Conditional Statement Checking Null

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, if-statement, unary-operator

I'm trying to figure out how to have a short, one line conditional statement.

If this date is not null, add the filter to the current list of filters:

`fromDt ?? filters.Add(FilterType.DateFrom, fromDt);`

Is there a way to do this? I know I could do..

`(fromDt != null) ? "something" : "something_else"`, but I don't need the 'else', and would really like to just use the `??` operator for null checking.

Comment: I'd encourage you not to do this - you are trading clarity for raw character count

Comment: You are making your code terrible. Luckily for your co-workers, there is no one-line way to do it without using an `if` statement.

Comment: This is just a side project of mine, and it's just something I want to figure out to use. I wouldn't use it in most [or any] business cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
if (fromDt != null) filters.Add(FilterType.DateFrom, fromDt);
```

First and foremost, your code should be readable. Even if your `??` code works, I wouldn't know what it does on first glimpse.

Comment: Actually, first and foremost your code should work. But only the tiniest smidgen behind that condition is that it should be readable and easy for others to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are attempting makes your code very difficult to read. Like [BrokenGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329769/brokenglass) said, you are trading clarity for raw character count.

This is the only "one line" solution C# supports.

```
if (fromDt != null) filters.Add(FilterType.DateFrom, fromDt);
```

But I encourage everyone to expand this to *at least* two lines (my preference is four with the braces).

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of the solution aside, following one-liner might give you *end* result you want while using `??`. Do not try this at home though.

`filters.Add(FilterType.DateFrom, fromDt ?? DateTime.MinValue)`

The idea is to set DateFrom to min possible value, essentially adding an open filter.

Comment: Would the down-voter like to elaborate? This __is__ a solution, is there any issue with this?

Comment: Probably because it's implying a sentinel value that will then need to be checked for. What if the thing calling `filters.Add` is a loop over a sequence of 1000000 items with only one non-null from date. You'd end up with a list of 999999 filters with the sentinel which need to be ignored and one filter that's real. Better to just end with one real filter.

Comment: @Shibumi, quoting Doctor Oreo "This is just a side project of mine, and it's just something I want to figure out to use. I wouldn't use it in most [or any] business cases." Every solution in software development can be invalidated with "what if the thing....". The requirement was to use certain syntactic constructs with no regard for performance, footprint, readability and common sense. Plus, quoting myself "Do not try this at home" hints at the fact that this answer is not to be applied to a loop with 1000000 iterations.

Comment: Either way, this is a valid answer to my question. It's definitely an interesting solution, and gives me something to work with.

Comment: @THX I would argue that *...with no regard for performance, footprint, readability and common sense.* was something that you added, rather than something that was part of the original specification.